# A generalized norm function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, norms, vector-spaces

We defined a new norm. The norm of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as
$$ N_P(x) = \min \{t \geq 0 : x \in t\cdot P\} \enspace,$$
where $P$ is a centrally symmetric and convex body centered at the origin point.

We prove that it is a norm.

1.Identity of indiscernibles.
Obviously, $N_P(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$.

2.Absolutely scalable.

Because of centrally symmetric property, $N_P(ax)=|a|N_P(x)$.

3.Triangle inequality.

Denote $N_P(x+y), N_P(x),N_P(y)$ as $t_0,t_1,t_2$ respectively. And let vectors $x+y,x,y$ go from the origin point and hit the border of $P$ at $a,b,c$ respectively.

Therefore $(x+y)=x+y$ implies $t_0\vec{a}=t_1\vec{b}+t_2\vec{c}$, implies $\vec{a}=\frac{t_1}{t_0}\vec{b}+\frac{t_2}{t_0}\vec{c}$

Suppose $t_0 > t_1+t_2$, thus $0\leq \frac{t_1}{t_0}+\frac{t_2}{t_0}<1$.

However, this contradict to the convex property because border $bac$ is not convex. QED

We realized this new norm consists all possible norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$, including $\ell_p$.

Because for any norm $N(\cdot)$, define $P=\{ x : N(x)\leq 1\}$, one can verify that $N_P=N$. It shows a simple fact: a norm is equivalent to the space which has unit norm.

Our question is, did anyone discover it before? What is the name? We googled it but did not get answers.

Comment: As the answer states, you are looking at a particular class of Minkowski functionals. But note that your conditions on $P$ are not sufficient to get a norm. Consider the case $n = 2$ and $P = \{ -1 < x < 1\}$. This set is convex and centrally symmetric, but $N_p((0,1)) = 0$. Similarly, you can consider the case where $P = \{ x = 0, |y| < 1\}$. In this case $N_p((1,0) = \infty$. Finally, if you allo your $P$ to be open (as I did in the first example), you really want to use $\inf$ instead of $\min$.

Comment: In convex geometry this is the reciprocal of the radial function of a convex body.

Answer (score 5):

These are called *Minkowski functionals*, see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional).
They come up in the study of locally convex vector spaces.